# Java - How do I format a float before and while displaying it?

Tags: java, floating-point, format

I saw someone post this question recently, but because they received bad votes/comments, they took it down right when I was going to answer it. Since it isn't very popular on stackoverflow, and since people convinced the user that it couldn't be done, I have chosen to post a Q&A on it.

The question: How can I format a float to have four decimals? (i.e. 1.4056)

For example, if the float is 1.8, it should display as 1.8000.
And if the float is 1.56789, it should display as 1.5679.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Use `String.format` for actually formatting the float itself, and the `System.out.printf()` to *display* the formatted float, without modifying the value.

String.format:

```
float test = 0;
test=Float.parseFloat(String.format("%1.4f", (float)1.123456));
```

This will store the value 1.1235 in 'test' (note that it rounds up). If we enter the float value 1.5, test will be 1.5 and not 1.5000 because it won't store unnecessary zeroes.

To display 1.5 as 1.5000, use the following statement:

```
System.out.printf("%1.4f", (float)/*or double*/1.5);
```

This will display the value with four decimals, regardless of their value. In the above statement, 1.5000 will be displayed. Again, it rounds up if needed.

(Please note that in formatting, %f works with floats and doubles. You can replace the above float numbers with doubles and the result will be the same)

Hope this helps whoever needs it!